# How compare relative frequencies between different sized groups (fish species)?

Tags: binomial-distribution, sample-size, biostatistics, frequency

I have gathered data from a number of studies on presence / absence of fish species at 4 locations (let's call them A-D) with different proximity to a structure. I am interested in knowing how frequently each of these species are recorded as present and compare the rates within and between locations.

My crux is that I have a lot of variation in sample sizes, both between locations and between species within locations.
I'v looked at 12 studies in total but not all studies has sampled all 4 locations. As a result, no location has been sampled more than 6-7 times total.
Additionally, not all studies has data on all species of fish. So sample sizes vary between fish species within each location. Specifically between: 0-7 for locations "A" and "D"; 0-6 for "B"; and 0-4 for "C".

I can make species within locations comparable by simply calculating relative frequency-of-presence.

But how should I treat my data to allow comparison between locations as well?

Comment: Can you tell us some details? Sample sizes? What kind of objects (it might matter, and anyhow, it gives us contextual information) Why the difference in sample sizes? ...

Comment: Sure! The objects in question are species of fish. I'v edited the post to  hopefully clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

*Simple solution*

You could start with comparisons between locations done for one species at a time. Just like you propose to compare different species within a location by examining the "relative frequency of presence," you compare locations for each single species the same way, with the "relative frequency of presence" for that species.

*Other potentially better possibilities*

One problem is that the studies might differ in their abilities to detect a species that's truly present. A study that samples for a longer time or over a larger area might find a species that a lower-scale study doesn't at the same location and time. That could bias your results depending on which studies evaluated which species at which locations. It would be better to work with actual numbers of members of each species that were found, if those are available, along with some estimate of the study scale to try to correct for such differences between studies.

It *might* be possible to do a more formal analysis of fish presence or fish counts with a binomial or a Poisson regression model that could take differences among studies into account. A [binomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_regression) might treat the studies as "random effects" having different baseline probabilities of finding a species present. A [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) could use a measure of study scale as an "offset" to normalize fish counts among the studies. Or you might treat fish counts with [log-linear analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis) to evaluate how combinations of location, species, and study lead to the observed counts. But from the way you describe the data, I feat that there might not be enough combinations of location and species covered by all the studies to do that.

A final possibility would be to treat this as a missing-data problem and try to use the information you have to estimate the values that might have been found if all studies examined all species at all locations. There are principled ways to do that, constructing multiple probabilistically generated complete data sets from what you have, a process called [multiple imputation](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/), and then adding the variability in results among the data sets to the other sources of variation. But it's hard to know if that would make sense with your data without more details about the missing-data pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! I completely agree that working with actual numbers would be best. Unfortunately, I chose to use simple P/A data to begin with because sampling methods and metrics differed so much between studies it made direct comparison difficult. So there's a fair measure of uncertainty in my data, but it what i have.  Binomial regression seems it might be fitting. I'll look into that! I found fisher's exact test worked out as a simple solution, but that still leaves a way to report my relative frequency values whilst highlighting the differences in location sample size.